# Laravel custom User Model- MD5 - TripleDES Encryption

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, laravel, encryption, laravel-5

I'm adapting an old .net app with SQL DB to a Laravel framework. I've finished the migration and models, the sqlsrv driver and the connection file are working, but I'm having issues with the encryption method used. I don't know much about encryption.

The app on production have this encryption functions:

```
    private string Key = "";
    private readonly byte[] IVector = new byte[8] { 17, 19, 25, 17, 10, 32, 161, 24 };

    public string Encrypt(string inputString)
    {

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString);
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider MD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        tripleDes.Key = MD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key));
        tripleDes.IV = IVector;
        ICryptoTransform ITransform = tripleDes.CreateEncryptor();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ITransform.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
    }
```

On Laravel, the **Auth::attempt** works but the credentials don't match, I think is because the encryption method.

```
    Auth::attempt([
        'userName' => 'hard_coded_username',
        'password'  => 'hard_coded_password',
    ]);
```

I've check the different encryption methods to validate that.

```
$db_pass        =   'hard_codded_encrypted_password_from_db';
$md5            =   md5($db_pass);
$bcrypt         =   bcrypt($md5);
$encrypted      =   Crypt::encrypt($db_pass);
$encryptedMD5   =   Crypt::encrypt($md5);

dd($md5, $bcrypt, $encryptedMD5, $encrypted, $encryptedMD5);
```

So, how can I get this to work? any suggestion or guide will be appreciated.

Comment: The existing production code is horribly broken and insecure. This is your opportunity to fix it in the new version. TripleDES should not be used, MD5 should not be used (especially as a KDF), a fixed IV should not be used, the list goes on... Use AES, with a random IV generated from a CSPRNG, and a modern, safe KDF like PBKDF2. Try to use GCM mode if you can, otherwise use an HMAC for authentication. If you don't know much about encryption, then you are the wrong person for this job. The existing production code **is** insecure, and someone will exploit it sooner or later.

Comment: The .NET code is completely different from the Laravel code. Not sure what you're trying to do, but SO is not a code conversion service.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark thanks my friend, we are currently working on the new version with all the fixes need it. This issue is for a specific task but I'm sure we will work like you point out.

Comment: Thanks @MaartenBodewes you are right, Laravel and .NET are in fact completely different. I'm trying to solve a problem, I'm not looking for a code conversion service. I'm looking for a guide on this from experienced pro like you. -- More than 50 million professional and aspiring programmers visit Stack Overflow each month to help solve coding problems, develop new skills, and find job opportunities. --  https://stackoverflow.com/company

Answer (score 0):

maybe I did not explain myself well before. Developing in the new framework, with **Laravel**, I needed to log in using the old DB. I thought by mistake that the encryption of the password being different, needed some kind of configuration. But no, I just needed to use **bcrypt** in the getAuthPassword of the new user model, like this.

```
public function getAuthPassword() {
return bcrypt($this->userPassword);
}
```

Comment: This might be useful as a reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing